# Interpreting (yet another) 17th century German church record?

Tags: germany, palaeography, 17th-century, german-language

Very much on the same topic as an earlier question, [Interpreting 17th century German church record?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13946/interpreting-17th-century-german-church-record), I have found a lead for further research (quite obvious lead but my subscription on Archion had run out):

Two years after the birth of Henning Conrad (see previous post), another man with the same surname was born in the same town. This leads me to believe that it is a sibling of Henning Conrad with the possibility that the parents (or at least the fathers) name may be revealed.

A name registry book reveals:

[image]

> Warnecke Jolst/Jobst(?) Johann 75
>
> Source: Reg T 1673-1794,1823-1852 (Kirchenkreis Laatzen-Pattensen / Gestorf) Bild 82

On page 75 in the church book I find this record. My attempt to decipher the text was greatly helped by the answer to my previous post but unfortunately I once again fell short:

[image]

> ???? ?????? Jobst Warnekens Sohn Jobst Johan geboren ???? 17 Febr ????? zwischen 7 und 8. Getauft den 22. Gevatter ??? ??? ?? Johan von Jeinsen, ??? ???  ?????
>
> Source: KB 1673-1751 (Kirchenkreis Laatzen-Pattensen / Gestorf) Bild 47

Can someone help me decipher the full record?

**Update (more information to help clarify the unknowns):**

[image]

> Birth record of a probable sibling (Anna Dorothea) where the fathers name seems to be mentioned
>
> Source: KB 1673-1751 (Kirchenkreis Laatzen-Pattensen / Gestorf), page 85, #21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give it a try, although the image is quite grainy and some of it is not very well readable:

"??? Voigts ( a Vogt is a minor official -- "reeve" or "bailiff" is what I found as possible translations --- the 'i' could simply indicate a lengthening of the preceding vowel, which is consistent with current pronunciations --- the whole being a description of Jobst Warneke) Jobst Warnekens Sohn Jobst Johan (son of Jobst Warneken), born 17 Febr[uary]. (the year would be implicit in the page header or possibly in the running text when the current year started) abends zwischen 7 und 8 (between 7 and 8 p.m.), getaufft den 22 (baptised the 22d [of Feb]). Gevattern (godparents): 1. der kleine Junker (the little squire --- for you to sort out what "little" might mean in this context) Jobst Johann von Feinsen (?)..." There should be a second godparent, but I cannot make out the last five words of the record, and they do not seem to give a name, but rather a further description of the "little squire".

The last picture is equally hard to read,  but I will give it a shot:

"Hrn. (To Mr.) Jobst Warneken, Voigtens (bailiff, again), Anna Doroth[ea] gebohren d. 28. 7br (Sep 28) früh umb 6 (6 a.m.) Getaufft (baptized) d. 28. {same day}. Gevatter (godparents): Hn. Meyers Fraw Liebste (Mr. Meyer's wife), Anna Marg[aretha] Zinnemanns".

Comment: Awesome work, yet again, @user3697176 !
I think it should be Jeinsen and not Feinsen. There is a neighbor town called Jeinsen just 8km away from Gestorf.

Comment: I have a birth record from a sibling which I think could help finding out the first part of the name / title (???). I will attach it to this post as an update.